# How to solve T(n)=T(n-1)+ (n-1) by Iteration Method?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration, time-complexity, recurrence

Please can anyone help me with this:
Solve using iteration Method T (n) = T (n - 1) + (n - 1)

And prove that T (n) ∈Θ (n²)

Please, if you can explain step by step I would be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved an easy way :

```
T (n) = T (n - 1) + (n - 1)-----------(1)
//now submit T(n-1)=t(n)

T(n-1)=T((n-1)-1)+((n-1)-1)
T(n-1)=T(n-2)+n-2---------------(2)

now submit (2) in (1) you will get
i.e T(n)=[T(n-2)+n-2]+(n-1)
T(n)=T(n-2)+2n-3 //simplified--------------(3)

now, T(n-2)=t(n)
 T(n-2)=T((n-2)-2)+[2(n-2)-3]
T(n-2)=T(n-4)+2n-7---------------(4)
now submit (4) in (2) you will get
i.e T(n)=[T(n-4)+2n-7]+(2n-3)
T(n)=T(n-4)+4n-10 //simplified
............
T(n)=T(n-k)+kn-10

now, assume k=n-1

T(n)=T(n-(n-1))+(n-1)n-10
T(n)=T(1)+n^2-n-10
According to the complexity 10 is constant

So , Finally O(n^2)
```

Comment: If you understood the above explanation please accept it @Patterson Silva

Comment: I understood almost everything, in fact I got to step 4 by myself. I just did not understand this part of the ending:
T (n) = T (n- (n-1)) + (n-1) n-10
T (n) = T (1) + n ^ 2-n-10
How did "(n-1) n-10" turn "n ^ 2-n-10"?

Comment: Based on General form T(n)=T(n-k)+k, we know initial T(1)=0, then we need to submit k=n-1 then simplify , finally you will get T(n)=n^2-n-10;; then we can easily get O(n^2) @PattersonSilva

Answer (score 3):

```
T(n) = T(n - 1) + (n - 1)
      = (T(n - 2) + (n - 2)) + (n - 1)
      = (T(n - 3) + (n - 3)) + (n - 2) + (n - 1)
      = ...
      = T(0) + 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 3) + (n - 2) + (n - 1)
      = C + n * (n - 1) / 2
      = O(n2)
```

Hence for sufficient large `n`, we have:

```
n * (n - 1) / 3 ≤  T(n) ≤ n2
```

Therefore we have `T(n) = Ω(n²) and T(n) = O(n²)`, thus `T(n) = Θ (n²)`.

Answer (score 0):

T(n)-T(n-1) = n-1
T(n-1)-T(n-2) = n-2

By substraction

T(n)-2T(n-1)+T(n-2) = 1
T(n-1)-2T(n-2)+T(n-3) = 1

Again, by substitution

T(n)-3T(n-1)+3T(n-2)-T(n-3) = 0

Characteristic equation of the recursion is

x^3-3x^2+3x-1 = 0

or

(x-1)^3 = 0.

It has roots x_1,2,3 = 1,

so general solution of the recursion is

T(n) = C_1 1^n + C_2 n 1^n + C_3 n^2 1^n

or

T(n) = C_1 + C_2 n + C_3 n^2.

So,

T(n) = Θ(n^2).